# How close can I be to a bomb without getting blown up?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For some reason, bomb damage tends to be somewhat erratic in this game.  For example, on dust2, if I'm at mid double doors when the bomb explodes, I end up dying (around 25 hp left or so), whereas if I'm in the situations sometimes, I can by on lower cat and end up surviving with a minimal amount hp.

Question is, how far must I be away from a bomb to be safe from any potential injuries? I'd personally like to not get blown up over and over, and would like to also be consistently far away enough to not die so I wouldn't have to rebuy the next round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into a private game and use the following command:

> map_showbombradius

If you don't want to explore it yourself, there is an in depth, useful video guide here:

> 